Simplex method: why basic variables are dependent ones, & non-basic variables are independent ones?
In the Dantzig's book, it is stated for Simplex method, that the basic variables are dependent; while the non-basic variables are independent.
Am confused about this terminology, as the basis is initially composed only on non-decision variables, i.e. those variables that have zero coefficient in the objective function ($z$), of the augmented linear equations.
While the decision variable(s) enter into the basis, with the optimal solution needing at least one decision variable (&, at max. all decision variables), in the basis.
The book chose an example LPP, on page #65:
$$2x_1 + 2x_2 + 2x_3 +x_4 + 4x_5 =z $$
$$4x_1 + 2x_2 + 13x_3 +3x_4 + x_5 =17$$
$$x_1 + x_2 + 5x_3 +x_4 + x_5 =7 $$
while on the bottom of page #66, states the basic variables as dependent, and the non-basic variables as independent.
If any reason can be accorded for the same, please.

Is it clear that equation (3.9) can be written $$ Ix_B = \overline{b} - \overline{A}x_N \text{,} $$ explicitly writing the $x_B$ dependent on chosen values of the $x_N$?  Looking at the "spelled out" version in (3.11) is it plausible that changing one of the $x_N$, say $x_{m+1}$ alters the value of all or most of the $x_B$, but changing the value of one of the $x_B$ can be absorbed into the variables other than $x_{m+1}$, so each of the $x_N$ aren't unavoidably dependent on each $x_B$?

This is because the basis matrix is invertible.
$$Bx_B + Nx_N = b$$
$$x_B + B^{-1}Nx_N=B^{-1}b$$
$$Ix_B + \bar{A}x_N=\bar{b}$$
$$x_B=\bar{b}-\bar{A}x_N$$
Once we set the independent variable $x_N$, we then determine $x_B$, the dependent variables.

Kindly see my post at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4976374/424260.
