Pivoting in Simplex method, by new approach given in the book by James Strayer.
In the UG book by James Strayer, titled: Linear Programming & Its Applications; there is a distinct method (hereafter, referred to as the second method) used for pivoting. It differs from the method shown in the book by Dantzig (hereafter, referred to as the first method).
The differences are:

-Pivot element is not converted to $1,$ instead takes its reciprocal.
-Also, it doesn't convert the coefficients, in the same column as the pivot element, to zero, but multiplies them by $-\frac1{p}.$

The steps are shown on page #34, and are copied below, where the steps under consideration are Step #3, & #5:
The Pivot Transformation for Maximum and Minimum Tableaus:
(1) Choose a nonzero pivot entry p inside the tableau, but not in the objective function row/column or the $-1$ column/row. (Convention: Pivot entries are noted by a super-scripted asterisk ($*$).)
Note: will use the symbol @, instead of $*,$ in order to avoid confusion with the multiplication symbol.
(2) Interchange the variables corresponding to $p's$ row and column, leaving the signs behind.
(3) Replace $p$ by $\frac 1p.$
(4) Replace every entry q in the same row as $p$ by $\frac qp.$
(5) Replace every entry $r$ in the same column as $p$ by $\frac{-r}p.$
(6) Every entry $s$ not in the same row and not in the same column as $p$ determines a unique entry q in the same row as p and in the same column as s and a unique entry r in the same column as p and in the same row as s. Replace s by $\frac{(ps-qr)}p.$
The effect produced by the above steps is shown by the below matrix, with pivot element $p.$
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
...& -c_q => -c_q + \frac qp *c_p = \frac{-pc_q+qc_p}p & ... & -c_p => \frac {c_p}p & ...\\ \hline
...& ... & ... & ... & ...\\ \hline
...& s => s-r*\frac qp = \frac{(ps-qr)}p & ... &r => -\frac rp & ...\\ \hline
...& q =>  \frac qp & ... & p^@ => \frac1p^@
 & ... \\ \hline
...& ... & ... & ... & ...\\ \hline
\end{array}$$
The usual pivoting process, as stated also in the book by Dantzig, produces the below effect:
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
...& -c_q => -c_q + \frac qp *c_p = \frac{-pc_q+qc_p}p & ... & -c_p => 0 & ...\\ \hline
...& ... & ... & ... & ...\\ \hline
...& s => s-r*\frac qp = \frac{(ps-qr)}p & ... &r => r-r=0 & ...\\ \hline
...& q =>  \frac qp & ... & p^@ => 1 & ... \\ \hline
...& ... & ... & ... & ...\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Doubt #1: Want to ask why the modified approach works? 
Doubt #2: Even more important is the $\frac{(ps-qr)}p$ term, which replicates in both methods.
Am unable to find the logical significance of the $6$-th step, which seems more like finding the value of determinant after dividing by $p,$ of the matrix:
$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  s & r \\
  q & p^@ \\
 \end{array} \right)
$
Though, this applies to both methods, but have shown this applicable in the  iterations, for the second .
Doubt #3: Am unable to find the formula, when the element $s$ is not located in the matrix, as in Doubt#2 above.
Say, in the second iteration (for the second method); get five ((II), (III), (IV), (V)) elements in the matrix, that cannot be found using any formula:
$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
         & -118        &  \frac{16}5 (V) \\
  96 (I) & \frac{234}5 & \frac{-24}{75} (II)\\
  12 & \frac{128}5^@ & \frac{-33}{75} \\
  6 (III) & \frac{10}{75} & \frac{-1}{75} (IV) \\
 \end{array} \right)
$
Say, for the element (II) $=\frac{-24}{75},$ that occurs in the matrix:
$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  \frac{234}5 & \frac{-24}{75} \\
  \frac{128}5 & \frac{-33}{75} \\
 \end{array} \right)
$
Here, the desired answer should be $\frac{31}{64},$ but am getting the answer: $\frac{\frac{234}5*\frac{-33}{75}+\frac{128}5*\frac{24}{75}}{\frac{-33}{75}} = \frac{310}{11}$
Want to extend this doubt for the other three elements too, i.e. (III), (IV), (V); in the second iteration (for the second method); with $\frac{128}5$ as the pivot element:
Say, the computation of (V) has to be repeated simply as done in the first method, i.e. by $\frac{16}5 -\frac{11}{640}*118= \frac{75}{64},$ and cannot form any feasible matrix, which can only be:
$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
  s=\frac{16}5 & r=\frac{11}{640} \\
  q=118 & p=1 \\
 \end{array} \right)$
And, as can be seen at the bottom of this post, it is not possible to derive this matrix.

To highlight the new approach, have taken a modified version of the example asked here, and solved successfully using both (the first, & second) methods, i.e.:

the usual method, as shown in the Dantzig's book (&, in the second table above), vs
the method of concern here, as shown in the first table above.

Also, am including link for book pages: pg #30, pg#31-32, pg#33-34, pg #35-36, apart from the link for the book at archive.org, as provided in the first line.
Example LPP problem: 
The objective function is: Maximize $z = 150x_1 + 240x_2$
Resource constraint matrix, showing the three structural constraints ($C_1, C_2, C_3$) is:
$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
  50 & 24  \\
  30 & 33 \\
  10 & 75 \\
 \end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  x_1 \\
  x_2 \\
\end{array}\right)\leq
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  240 \\
  210 \\
  450 \\
\end{array}\right)$
with $$C1: 50x_1 + 24x_2 \le 240,$$ $$C2: 30x_1 + 33x_2 \le 210,$$ $$C3: 10x_1 + 75x_2 \le 450.$$
And, the two non-negativity constraints: $C4: x_1\geq 0, C5: x_2\geq 0.$
Pivoting using the first method:
Initial Iteration:
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\,  Basis & C_{i} & \text{Value of B.V.} & x_1 & x_2& s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & Ratio\\\hline
z  &   & & -150 & -240 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\ \hline
s_1  & 0  & 240 & 50 & 24 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{240}{10} = 10\\ \hline
s_2  & 0  & 210 & 30 & 33 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{210}{33} = \frac{70}{11} \approx 6.37\\ \hline
s_3  & 0  & 450 & 10 & 75^@ & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{450}{75} = 6 \\ \hline
z=0   & & Z_j & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   \\ \hline
& & C_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
& & C_j - Z_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
First iteration:
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\,  Basis & C_{i} & \text{Value of B.V.} & x_1 & x_2& s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & Ratio\\\hline
z  &   & & -150+\frac 2{15}*240= -118 & -240+240=0 & 0 & 0 & 0+\frac1{75}*240 = \frac{16}5 & \\ \hline
s_1  & 0  & 240-6*24= 96 & 50 -\frac 2{15}*24=\frac{234}5& 24-24=0 & 1 & 0 & 0-\frac{24}{75}= -\frac8{25} & \frac{96*5}{234} = \frac{240}{117}\\ \hline
s_2  & 0  & 210-6*33=12 & 30-\frac2{15}*33= \frac{128}5^@ & 33-33=0 & 0 & 1 & 0-\frac{33}{75}=-\frac{11}{25} & 12*\frac 5{128}= \frac{15}{32}=0.469\\ \hline
x_2  & 240  & \frac{450}{75} = 6 & \frac{2}{15} & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac1{75} & 6*\frac{15}2 = 45 \\ \hline
z=6*240= 1,440   & & Z_j & 0 & 240 & 0 & 0 & \frac1{75}*240 = \frac{16}5 &   \\ \hline
& & C_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
& & C_j - Z_j & 150 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{16}5 &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Second iteration:
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\,  Basis & C_{i} & \text{Value of B.V.} & x_1 & x_2& s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & Ratio\\\hline
z  &   & & -118+118=0 & 0 & 0 & \frac5{128}*118=\frac{245}{64}  & \frac{16}5-\frac{11}{640}*118 = \frac{1024-649}{320}=\frac{375}{320}= \frac{75}{64} & \\ \hline
s_1  & 0  & 96-\frac{15}{32}*\frac{234}5=\frac{1536-351}{16}= \frac{1185}{16} & \frac{234}5-\frac{234}5=0& 0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac8{25}+ \frac{11}{128*5}*\frac{234}5=\frac{-512+1287}{64*25}=\frac{775}{64*25}=\frac{31}{25}& \\ \hline
x_1  & 150  & 12*\frac5{128}=\frac{15}{32} & \frac{128}5*\frac5{128}=1 & 0 & 0 & \frac5{128} & -\frac{11}{25}*\frac5{128}=-\frac{11}{640} & \\ \hline
x_2  & 240  & 6-\frac{15}{32}*\frac{2}{15}= \frac{95}{16} & \frac{2}{15}-\frac{2}{15}=0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac5{128}*\frac2{15}=-\frac1{192} & \frac1{75}+(\frac{11}{640}*\frac{2}{15}=\frac{11}{64*75})=\frac1{64} &  \\ \hline
z=\frac{15}{32}*150+\frac{95}{16}*240= 1495.3125   & & Z_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & -\frac1{192}*240=-\frac{5}{4} & -\frac{11}{640}*150 + \frac1{64}*240 = \frac{-1650+2400}{640}=\frac{75}{64} &   \\ \hline
& & C_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
& & C_j - Z_j & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{5}{4} & -\frac{75}{64} &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Though the $C_j-Z_j$ measure fails to stop at the optimum solution, given by $x_1 = \frac{15}{32}, x_2= \frac{95}{16};$ but that have asked earlier too on mse; and is currently beyond the scope of the OP. 
The above solution is proved correct here. 
Here, want to show the two approaches to the pivot element, so now the second method (approach of James Strayer's book) follows:
Pivoting using the second method:
Initial iteration:
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\,  Basis & C_{i} & \text{Value of B.V.} & x_1 & x_2& s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & Ratio\\\hline
z  &   & & -150 & -240 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\ \hline
s_1  & 0  & 240 & 50 & 24 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{240}{10} = 10\\ \hline
s_2  & 0  & 210 & 30 & 33 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{210}{33} = \frac{70}{11} \approx 6.37\\ \hline
s_3  & 0  & 450 & 10 & 75^@ & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{450}{75} = 6 \\ \hline
z=0   & & Z_j & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   \\ \hline
& & C_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
& & C_j - Z_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
First iteration:
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\,  Basis & C_{i} & \text{Value of B.V.} & x_1 & x_2& s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & Ratio\\\hline
z  &   & & -150 + \frac{10}{75}*240 = -118  <Or> \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  s=-150 & r=-240 \\
  q=10 & p=75 \\
 \end{array} \right)
= \frac{-150*75 -(-240*10)}{75} =-118 & -\frac{-240}{75}=\frac{16}5& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\ \hline
s_1  & 0  & 240-6*24=96 <Or> \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  s=240 & r=24 \\
  q=450 & p=75 \\
 \end{array} \right)
= \frac{240*75 - 24*450}{75} =96 & 50-\frac{10}{75}*24=\frac{234}5 <Or> \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  s=50 & r=24 \\
  q=10 & p=75 \\
 \end{array} \right)
= \frac{50*75 - 24*10}{75} =\frac{234}5& -\frac{24}{75} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 96*\frac{5}{234}=\frac{240}{117} \\ \hline
s_1  & 0  & 210-6*33=12<Or> \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  s=210 & r=33 \\
  q=450 & p=75 \\
 \end{array} \right)
= \frac{240*75 - 24*450}{75} =12  & 30-\frac{10}{75}*33=\frac{128}5 <Or> \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  s=30 & r=33 \\
  q=10 & p=75 \\
 \end{array} \right)
= \frac{30*75 - 10*33}{75} =\frac{128}5^@ & \frac{-33}{75} & 0 & 1 & 0 &12*\frac{5}{128}=\frac{15}{32} \\ \hline
x_2  & 240  & \frac{450}{75}=6 & \frac{10}{75} & \frac1{75} & 0 & 0 & \frac1{75} & 6*\frac{75}{10}=45\\ \hline
z=6*240= 1,440   & & Z_j & 0 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   \\ \hline
& & C_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
& & C_j - Z_j & 150 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Second iteration:
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\,  Basis & C_{i} & \text{Value of B.V.} & x_1 & x_2& s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & Ratio\\\hline
z  &   & & 118*\frac5{128}= \frac{59*5}{64} & (V) & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\ \hline
s_1  & 0  & (I) 96-\frac{234}5*\frac{15}{32}=\frac{1185}{16}<Or> \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  s=96 & r=\frac{234}5 \\
  q=12 & p=\frac{128}5 \\
 \end{array} \right)
= \frac{96*\frac{128}5 - \frac{234}5*12}{\frac{128}5}=\frac{1185}{16} & -\frac{234}5*\frac{5}{128}=-\frac{117}{64} & (II) -\frac{24}{75} + \frac{11}{5*128}*\frac{234}5 =\frac{-512+1287=775}{25*64}= \frac{31}{64}& 1 & 0 & 0 & \\ \hline
x_1  & 150  & 12*\frac{5}{128}=\frac{15}{32} & \frac5{128} & \frac{-33}{75}*\frac5{128}=\frac{-11}{5*128} & 0 & \frac{5}{128}  & 0 & \\ \hline
x_2  & 240  & (III) 6-(\frac{10}{75}*\frac{15}{32}=\frac1{16})=\frac{95}{16} & -\frac{10}{75}*\frac5{128}=-\frac1{192} & (IV) \frac1{75} & 0 & 0 & \frac1{75} & \\ \hline
z=\frac{15}{32}*150+\frac{95}{16}*240= 1495.3125 & & Z_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   \\ \hline
& & C_j & 150 & 240 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
& & C_j - Z_j & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
The match of the optimum value for $(x_1=\frac{15}{32}, x_2=\frac{95}{16}(III)),$ as by the earlier method; assures that the computation method for $x_2$ is correct.
But, as stated in Doubt #3 earlier, it is difficult to form the matrix, as say for (V).

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be the independent variables and $t_1, \ldots t_m$ tbe the dependent variables.
Suppose row k and column $l$ in Tucker Tableau is the pivot, i.e. we will make $t_k$ independent and $x_l$ dependent in our pivoting.
Our previous constraints are of the following form:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}x_j-b_i =-t_i, \forall i \in \{1, \ldots m\} $$
where $A_{kl}=p.$
Now let's express $x_l$ in terms of $t_k$ and the other $x_j, j \ne l$.
First let's examine row $k$:
$$px_l + \sum_{j=1, j\ne l}^n A_{kj}x_j -b_k = -t_k$$
$$t_k + \sum_{j=1, j\ne l}^n A_{kj}x_j -b_k = -px_l$$
$$\frac1pt_k + \sum_{j=1, j\ne l}^n \frac{A_{kj}}px_j -\frac{b_k}p = -x_l$$
This is why step $(3)$ and step $(4)$ is as such.
Now, let's examine another row, $i \ne k$.
$$\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}x_j-b_i =-t_i$$
$$\sum_{j=1, j \ne l}^n A_{ij}x_j + A_{il}x_l-b_i =-t_i$$
$$\sum_{j=1, j \ne l}^n A_{ij}x_j - A_{il}\left( \frac1pt_k + \sum_{j=1, j\ne l}^n \frac{A_{kj}}px_j -\frac{b_k}p\right)-b_i = -t_i$$
$$-\frac{A_{il}}{p}t_k + \sum_{j=1, j\ne l}^n \left( \frac{pA_{ij}-A_{il}A_{kj}}{p}\right)x_j - \left(\frac{b_ip-A_{il}b_k}{p} \right) = -t_i$$
That is why step $(5)$ and $(6)$ is as such.
Notice that a variable is either a dependent variable or independent variable, it can't be both at the same time.

Seems from your answer (though, am unable to see it clearly) that for elements in the second iteration; for the four elements $(II), (III), (IV), (V),$ (which are not lying in the same row/column, as of the pivot element) matrix formation ($\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
s & r \
q & p^@ \
\end{array} \right)
$) is not possible, as is possible for the element $(I).$ If am correct, request to elaborate it some more, by using any one of these four elements.

Notice that a variable is either a dependent variable or independent variable, it can't be both at the same time. The basic variables shouldn't be there in Strayer's representation.

Thanks a lot, but request still if there could have been elaboration given by any of the four elements.

Kindly help with finding proof, to my post at : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4981477/424260.

I am currently travelling

has the problem been solved?

Not really, but would request you to see my today's problem first at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4998830/424260

Please help with my post at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5015226/424260
