Proof for affine ciphers being distinct.
For affine cipher, consider it over the set of $26$ english alphabets, let $V=\{a=0, b=1, c=2,\cdots, z=25\}.$ Let the multiplicative key be: $j,$ with $(j, 26)=1,$ i.e. $j \in \{1,3,5, 7, 9, 11, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25\}.$ 
And, the additive key $i$ is taken from the set $V.$
The number of affine ciphers possible, are hence: $|j|*|i|=12*26= 312.$
For the integer values for the english alphabets from $a=0,$ to $z=25;$ have the distinct affine ciphers, for input alphabet $z' \in V,$ as:
$z'+a = z'+0 = z', z'+1, z'+2,\cdots, z'+25;$
$3z'+a = 3z'\pmod {26}, 3z'+1\pmod {26}, 3z'+2\pmod {26},\cdots, 3z'+25\pmod {26};$
$5z'\pmod {26}, 5z'+1\pmod {26}, 5z'+2\pmod {26},\cdots, 5z'+25\pmod {26};$
$\vdots$
$25z'\pmod {26}, 25z'+1\pmod {26}, 25z'+2\pmod {26},\cdots, 25z'+25\pmod {26};$
But, it is difficult to see that all the $312$ ciphers are distinct.
So, is there a proof for showing the distinctness of these ciphers?
Assuming as above, the multiplicative & additive keys being $j, i;$ the mapping function for encryption is $E(j, i, z),$ yielding cipher-text $C,$ for alphabet $z',$ given by: $C=E(j, i, z'): (j\cdot z' + i)\mod 26.$
Also, the decryption function for the cipher text $C,$ yields plaintext alphabet $z'.$ It is given by:  $z' = D(j,i, C): j^{-1} (z' - i) \mod {26}.$
Can the proof be explained in terms of the above mapping functions?

So, what you want is to show that if $ E(j_1, i_1, z ) = E(j_2, i_2, z) , \forall z$, then $ j_1 = j_2 ,  i_1 = i_2$. How can we show that is true? $\quad$ Hint: Given a valid affine cipher, how can we recover $j$? $i$?

@CalvinLin That is equivalent to stating: $(j_1\cdot z +i_1 )\mod 26 = (j_2\cdot z +i_2)\mod 26;$ with $j_1, j_2 \in {1,3,5,7,9,11,15,17,19,21,23,25}$ & $i_1, i_2.$

(Great! You're approaching this in a different manner than I intended from my hint, and it still works) Let's rewrite that as, $ (j_1 - j_2) z + (i_1 - i_2) \equiv 0 \forall z$. Can you show that if $ j_1 \neq j_2$, then there is some $z$ where the expression is not 0? $\quad$ And if $ j_1 = j_2$, then can you show that $i_1 = i_2$?

@CalvinLin Seems the problem lies in having two sets of two variables, to be proven equal; rather than one. I.e., need not only show that $j_1 = j_2,$ but also $i_1 = i_2.$

Indeed, we want to show that $(j_1, i_1) = (j_2, i_2)$. it's not clear to me why that results in a problem that can't be fixed. EG In my second comment, I recommend that you first show that $j_1 = j_2$, and then use that to show that $i_1 = i_2$.

@CalvinLin First task is to show by example, a contradiction s.t. if $j_1 \ne  j_2,$ then there is any $z'\in V,$ where $E(j_1, i_1, z') - E(j_2, i_2,z') \ne 0.$ Say, $z'=c(=2), $ & $j_1=3, j_2=5;$ have for $i_1=i_2=0;$ $j_1\cdot z' +i_1=6,$ & $j_2\cdot z' + i_2 =10.$ For any $i_2\in {0,1,\cdots, 25};$ get values for $E(5,i_2,z')$ as ${10,11,\cdots, 35}.$ None of these values match $6.$ But problem starts with $j_1=5, j_2=3$ instead, as $E(5,0,c)=10.$ While, $E(3,j_2,c)$ takes values: $6,7,8,9,10,\cdots.$ Here, match occurs for $i_2=4.$ More matches can occur, say $E(5,3,c) = E(3,7,c)=13.$

@CalvinLin My last comment shows by example, for contradiction; that such proof is not possible. I.e., the $312$ values are not distinct.

It seems to me that you're not properly taking the counter positive of "for all", which would be "there exists". The requirement of distinctness of 2 affine ciphers is that they do not agree on ALL values, though It is possible for 2 affine ciphers to agree on some (but not all) values.

It's not hard to see that all these maps are distinct.  Suppose we have affine maps $f,g$ mod $26$ as $f(x)=jx+k$ and $g(x)=mx+n$ where $j$ and $m$ are units.  You wish to prove that $f=g$ if and only if $j=m$ and $k=n$.  Reading this in the contrapositive accounts for all $312$ mappings being distinct.  The direction $\Leftarrow$ is automatic.
For the other, suppose that $f=g$.  Then $f(0)=g(0)$ and so $k=n$.  But we also have $f(1)=g(1)$ and this gives $j+k =m+k$ and hence $j=m$.  Done.
Note that this argument is perfectly valid for affine encryption in any modulus.

Please tell how to show fault in the reasoning in my second last comment, to the OP; that serves to state that the $312$ values are not distinct.

It is certainly possible that for distinct $f$ and $g$ one might have one particular point $x_0$ where $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$.  That does not mean that $f$ and $g$ are not-distinct (i.e., equal everywhere).

Am not clear. If $E(5,3,c(=2)) = E(3,7,c(=2)),$ then how distinctness arises for all $312$ possible values for $z'=c(=2)?$

Equal means that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$.  "Distinct" means that for some $x_0$ you have $f(x_0)\neq g(x_0)$.

To wit, consider $f(x) = x + 6$ and $g(x) = 3x+ 4$.  These are distinct because $f(0)=6$ yet $g(0)=4$.  However, they agree at $x=1$, but this single agreement does not mean that $f$ and $g$ are equal.

Still, you talk about functions being distinct; & not all the values taken up as distinct (here, which is a fixed set of $312$ values). I meant by OP, the 'set of $312$ values' being distinct. In that sense, can only state that the two functions $E(j_1, i_1, z'), E(j_2, i_2, z')$ are distinct, for any plaintext alphabet $z'.$.

Sorry, I do not understand your point at all.

The functions $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x^2$ are distinct functions, but you still have $f(0) = g(0) = 0$. As long as you show there's at least one point where they disagree you can say that they're different functions.

@ConMan Please vet: the two functions - $$E(j_1=5, i_1=3, z'=c(=2)), E(j_2=3, i_2=7, z'=c(=2))$$ each have $312$ solutions; with $\ge 1$ solutions common between the two functions. But, they also have $\ge 1$ solutions distinct for each of the two functions. Hence, count $312$ distinct solutions for each of the two functions.

@ConMan Please state that given the size of the alphabet, i.e. $|V|=26,$ can we derive a formula for the number of distinct solutions, given $|j|=12, |i|=26?$

@Randall Sorry, the wording in my comment is confusing. It should be framed as: Still your answer talks in terms of the two functions $E(j_1=5, i_1=3, z'=c(=2)), E(j_2=3, i_2=7, z'=c(=2))$ being distinct, & not that their solution space of $312$ pair of values of $(j_1,i_2), (j_2,i_2)$ are unique. Some pairs of values overlap, leading to less than $312*2$ distinct values as the solution space for the two functions. Though, it is obvious by earlier example that the two functions have at least one unique pair of values. Please note am assuming the alphabet $z'$ as common, to the two functions.

I do not understand and I don't think I can help anymore.  The meaning of "there are 312 distinct affine maps" is exactly what I have phrased in my answer and comments.  Any other interpretation of that phrase is just wrong.  You seem to say the ciphers are "distinct" means that all 312 ciphers applied to one symbol $z'$ leads to 312 different outcomes, which is impossible since the alphabet has only 26 characters.

@Randall Sorry, for confusing the '$312$ affine mappings', from $26$ plain-text alphabets $z'\in V,$ to the set of $C\in V.$ The choice of the phrase 'solution space' is the cause. Should have been more cautious. My last comment is restated as: If two functions share some part of the solution space (i.e., the pair specifying an input plaintext $z'\in V,$ mapping to ciphertext $C\in V);$ with at least one distinct mapping, for each of the two functions; then both functions have the set of maps $(z',C)$ as their solution space, including the shared mappings. It is an onto (not, one-to-one) map.

Define the encryption function $f_{j,i}: \{0,\ldots, 25\} \to \{0,\ldots, 25\}$ with the rule $f_{j,i}(z)=z\cdot j+i \pmod{26}.$
$j$ is an element from $\{q \in \mathbb{Z}^+: \gcd(26, q)=1, q < 26\}$ and $i$ is an element from $\{0, \ldots, 25\}$.
We want to show that if $(j, i) \ne (j', i')$, then we can find a $z$ such that  $f_{j,i} (z) \ne f_{j', i'}(z)$. That is we want to find a $z$ such that $j\cdot z + i \not \equiv j' \cdot z + i'\pmod{26}$.
We consider a few cases:

Case 1: if $i \ne i'$, in that case, we just have to pick $z$ to be $0$.

Case 2: if $i= i'$ but $j \ne j'$, in that case, we just have to pick $z$ to be $1$.


Thus, we have illustrated that all the $312$ encryption functions are distinct.
