Transportation problem - have doubts in framing the problem, to form equivalent problem.

A XYZ company is hired by a retailer to transport goods from its warehouses in cities: $A$ & $B,$ to its outlet stores in the cities: $C$ and $D.$ The XYZ company is contracted to deliver $30$ vehicles each month to deliver goods. The company determines that it will need to send at least $12$ of the vehicles to the location $C,$ and at least $13$ vehicles to the location $D.$ At least $15$ vehicles can come from the warehouse $A,$ & at least $20$ vehicles can come from the warehouse $B.$ The truck company wants to minimize the number of miles placed on its trucks. How many trucks should be sent out from each warehouse location and how much each outlet should receive, to achieve the minimum total number of miles run.
The distance table from each warehouse to each outlet, in miles:
$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline  & A & B \\ \hline C & 24 & 31 \\ \hline D & 20 & 38 \\ \hline  \end{array}$
Formulate its dual and solve the LPP.

The objective function, to be minimized, is in terms of the distance in miles run, in total. So, it is given by: $z = 24x_{AC} + 20x_{AD} + 31x_{BC} + 38x_{BD},$ where the variables are:
$x_{AC} =$ # of trucks sent from the warehouse $A,$ to the outlet $C,$ 
$x_{AD} =$ # of trucks sent from the warehouse $A,$ to the outlet $D,$ 
$x_{BC} =$ # of trucks sent from the warehouse $B,$ to the outlet $C,$ 
$x_{BD} =$ # of trucks sent from the warehouse $B,$ to the outlet $D.$ 
Other constraints are:
$C1: x_{AC} + x_{AD} + x_{BC} + x_{BD} \leq 30,$
$C2: x_{AC} + x_{BC} \geq 12,$
$C3: x_{AD} + x_{BD} \geq 13,$
$C4: x_{AC} + x_{AD} \geq 15,$
$C5: x_{BC} + x_{BD} \geq 20.$
Also, there are non-negativity constraints on the four variables given.

Doubt #1: Equivalent transportation problem is :
$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline  & A & B & Total \ demand\\ \hline C & 24 & 31 & 12\\ \hline D & 20 & 38 & 13 \\ \hline Total \ Supply & 15 & 20 & 35 \\ \hline \end{array}$
Am not sure if am correct to state the sum of rows as total supply, and the sum of columns as total demand?
Also, if am correct, then there are two more doubts, as stated below:
Doubt #2: Is it a feasible problem, as the total number of trucks are $30,$ while the minimum number of trucks to be sent from warehouse $A, B$ are $= 15+20 = 35.$
Or, must modify the condition of the total number of trucks to be $\geq 35?$
Doubt #3: Also, need add a dummy row to the equivalent transportation table, as below, as the row and column sums do not match.
$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline  & A & B & Total \ demand\\ \hline C & 24 & 31 & 12\\ \hline D & 20 & 38 & 13\\ \hline  & 0 & 0 & 10 \\ \hline Total \ Supply & 15 & 20 & 35 \\ \hline \end{array}$
But, then the $C1$ constraint need be modified to have $35$ on the rhs!


Doubt #4: Once, the above three doubts are cleared, then am not sure how the dual is to be useful;  as it is stated in the problem, that need convert it to its dual. 
But, for that need convert the original LPP to the $AX = B$, where $X = \left(\begin{array}{c}
  x_{AC} \\
  x_{AD} \\
  x_{BC} \\
  x_{BD} \\
\end{array}\right), A$ is the matrix of coefficients, given by: $\left(\begin{array}{c}
  1 \ 1  \ 1  \ 1 \\
  1 \ 0  \ 1  \ 0 \\
  0 \ 1  \ 0  \ 1 \\
  1 \ 1  \ 0  \ 0 \\
  0 \ 0  \ 1  \ 1 \\
\end{array}\right),$ and $B=\left(\begin{array}{c}
  30 \\
  12 \\
  13 \\
  15 \\
  20 \\
\end{array}\right).$
Before that, need add slack variable ($s_1$) to the $C1$ constraint, & surplus variables ($S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4$) & artificial variables ($A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$ to the rest of the constraints from $C2\text{ to }C5.$
The modified constraints are:
$C1: x_{AC} + x_{AD} + x_{BC} + x_{BD} + s_1 = 30,$
$C2: x_{AC} + x_{BC} -S_1 + A_1 = 12,$
$C3: x_{AD} + x_{BD} -S_2 + A_2 = 13,$
$C4: x_{AC} + x_{AD} -S_3 + A_3 = 15,$
$C5: x_{BC} + x_{BD} -S_4 + A_4 = 20.$
Am confused in this part too, as not able to find any solved example, that handles the transportation problem using the dual of its LPP; that has inequalities in its constraints, as in this problem.


Summary: IMO, this is a badly phrased question.

It depends on what do you mean by sum of row.

For example, $x_{AC}+x_{AD}$ is the number of vehicle sent from location $A$ (supply).

You are right, it is not feasible. If we read the question again, the phrasing is strange. It is likey that



At least 15 vehicles can come from the warehouse , & at least 20 vehicles can come from the warehouse .

should have been

At most 15 vehicles can come from the warehouse , & at most 20 vehicles can come from the warehouse .


To fulfil the terms of the contract, my interpretation is that we still need to send exactly $30$ vehicles though $25$ vehicles would satisfy the requirement of the retailers.

Now, let's write down the primal LPP:
$$\min 24x_{AC}+20x_{AD} + 31x_{BC}+38x_{BD}$$
$$x_{AC}+x_{AD}+x_{BC}+x_{BD}=30 \tag{A}$$
$$x_{AC}+x_{BC} \ge 12 \tag{B}$$
$$x_{AD}+x_{BD} \ge 13 \tag{C}$$
$$x_{AC}+x_{AD} \le 15 \tag{D}$$
$$x_{BC}+x_{BD}\le 20 \tag{E}$$
$$x \ge 0$$
Now, let's write down the dual:
$$\max 30p_1 + 12p_2 + 13p_3 + 15p_4 + 20p_5$$
$$p_1 + p_2 + p_4 \le 24 \tag{1}$$
$$p_1 + p_3 + p_4 \le 20 \tag{2}$$
$$p_1 + p_2+p_5 \le 31 \tag{3}$$
$$p_1 + p_3+p_5 \le 38 \tag{4}$$
$$p_2 \ge 0, p_3 \ge 0, p_4 \le 0, p_5 \le 0$$

Now, let's think of how to solve them.
A few observations:


$p_1$ is a high-valued variable.
Vehicles from warehouse $A$ is cheaper compared to vehicle form warehouse $B$. I would guess that $p_5=0$ and $p_4 \ne 0$.



From the above $2$ observations and since $p_1$ is at most $31$. By setting $p_1=31, p_2=p_3=0$, $p_4=-11$, we found a dual solution with objective value $(30)(31)-11(15)=930-165=765$.

Now, let's find the corresponding primal solution. From the dual solution that we proposed, constraint $(1)$ and constraint $(4)$ are not active. $x_{AC}=x_{BD}=0$. Also, constraint $(D)$ should be active since the corresponding dual variable is non-zero. We have $x_{AD}=15$ and $x_{BC}=15$. The corresponding objective function is $(20)(15)+(31)(15)=51(15)=510+255=765$. Since there are no duality gap, we have proven optimality.



Have two doubts. Doubt #1: Request why the constraints of $C2:x_{AC}+x_{BC}\geq 12,C3: x_{AD}+x_{BD}\geq 13$ are 'still' allowed rather than being changed to reflect 'at-max', rather than 'at-least'; i.e. there is $\leq,$ instead of $\geq?$ Doubt #2: Why is dual needed? Is it because it converts all constraints to the ≤ form?

I am guessing what the questions are asking, if you changed them to at most, summing $C2$ and $C3$ up will give you an upperbound of $25$ and there won't be any feasible solution. I wouldn't say it is needed, after all, you can always do simplex method. However, I guess the solution for the dual LP and recover the solution for the primal LP to verify that they are optimal.

Please answer my first doubt, as asked in my first comment.

I am guessing what the questions are asking, if you changed them to at most, summing 2 and 3 up will give you an upperbound of 25 and there won't be any feasible solution. In fact, if you are at the receiving end, you want assurance of minimal number of vehicles to reach your location.
