Two typos in the book by Joseph O'Rourke.
The book by O'Rourke, titled: Computational Geometry in C, Second Edition; states on page #64:


A convex combination of points $x_1,\cdots, x_k$ is a sum of the form $\alpha_1x_1+\cdots+ \alpha_kx_k$ with $\alpha_i \ge 0,\ \forall i$ and $\alpha_1+\cdots+ \alpha_k = 1.$ Thus a line segment consists of all convex combinations of its endpoints, and a triangle consists of all convex combinations of its three corners. In three dimensions, a tetrahedron is the convex combinations of its four corners.
The convex hull of a set of points $S$ is the set of all convex combinations of points of $S.$


First issue concerns the last statement, in line #3, seems erroneous, as it it should be: ...combination...''; though this seems to be treated as a minor typo, and is not listed here.
Second issue concerns with the defn. of the convex hull, as given in line #4; as it is stated to be not a unique convex combination, that involves the minimum possible perimeter for a given set of a number of points.
It makes a meaningless statement, due to not stating the given combination as: '...a particular set...$S$ with the minimum perimeter.'
This serious omission should fall under the category of an error, though this also is not listed in the link stated above.

Do you mean "Joseph O'Rourke"?

You had some serious typos when quoting from the book.

@Gary I quoted a very small portion, so please tell what is that typo(s).

The definition labeled 4 appears to be the standard one to me. In the plane, this defines a convex set, and it's a theorem that among all convex sets containing $S$, it's the one with minimum perimeter (when $S$ is compact, so that the perimeter is even defined!) For the first error, maybe "a tetrahedron is the set of all convex combinations..." would be better, but that's clearly the intent by analogy with the previous two examples.

I have fixed them. E. g. $\alpha_1x_1,\cdots, \alpha_kx_k
$ in place of $\alpha_1x_1+\cdots+ \alpha_kx_k$, and $\alpha_1+\alpha_k=1$ in place of $\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_k=1$.

@Gary Sorry for that, am still shocked to see that.

@JohnHughes Unclear as you first state that the defn labelled 4 is a std definition; but then agree that the defn of a convex hull, takes into consideration the min perimeter. Similarly, your explanation for the first error, is unclear.

@jiten The definition given in (4.) is meaningful, but I don't think there is a reasonable one with the perimeter. For example, you can take $S = \left{\left( n, \frac{1}{n} \right) : n \in \mathbb{N} \right} \cup \left{\left( \frac{1}{n}, n \right) : n \in \mathbb{N} \right}$. Note that in (4.), $S$ is not required to be finite. Then (4.) gives a definition for the convex hull of $S$. But how would you define the convex hull of $S$ using a notion of perimeter?

@Smiley1000 Request to please elaborate your example. Also, even if the criteria for 'convex hull' having the minimum perimeter is wrong; but it should have at least the criteria of: 'having the minimum possible number of points, that encompass the entire set of points.' Such a criteria, would definitely not cover all possible convex combinations of the set of points in S.

No. I said it was standard, and that the observation about perimeter is a theorem, which would typically follow such a definition somewhat later. As for my lack of clarity...well, you get what you pay for. You probably wouldn't like the books that I've written any more than you like O'Rourke's, eh?

@JohnHughes Please state your written book's name. Thanks in anticipation.

Re: "minimum possible number of points": the convex hulls of any two sets containing at least two points have the same cardinality, so this notion of "minimum number of points" is just silly. The fact that the convex hull $C$ defined by line 4 has the property that it's the intersection of all convex sets containing $S$ is another (very important) theorem, not part of a definition.

I'm co-author of several editions of "Computer Graphics: Principle and Practice." As with most books of more than 500 pages, it contains quite a few errors, despite our best efforts. But not everything that a reader thinks is wrong is actually an error, as we've learned from decades of errata submissions.

@Smiley1000 Your example is for an hyperbola with both ends touching each one of the two axes, and passing through (1,1). And, how you purport to show the failure of defn of convex hull, based on minimum perimeter, is not clear. Please elaborate. My (earlier stated) second criteria of defining a convex hull as the smallest convex set that contains all the points in the set; is still waiting for your kind response.

@jiten It will be very difficult to give a counterexample to the perimeter-based definition, since I have not been provided a clear version of the perimeter-based definition. Perhaps you could do that, and then we can discuss what problems it might have.

@jiten "My (earlier stated) second criteria of defining a convex hull as the smallest convex set that contains all the points in the set" That is completely correct. There is, however, an equivalent definition: As the set of all convex combinations.

As @JohnHughes remarked, the context in (3) is the previous two sentences: a line segment, then a triangle, so for the tetrahedron the phrase "consists of all convex combinations of" is shortened to avoid the tedium of repetition. Yes, it can be misread.

Concerning (4), in my later textbook, I make this a theorem rather than a definition. The definition is the intersection of all containing convex sets. Incidentally, the quoted passage was penned almost exactly 30 years ago. :-)


The convex hull of a set of points $$ is the set of all convex combinations of points of $$.

The definition doesn't impose any conditions on $S$ and as discussed in the comment, this is the standard definision.
For example, let $S_1=\{(1,0), (0,0), (0,1)\}$, then $conv(S_1)$ is a triangle with corners being $(1,0), (0,0), (0,1)$.
We can also let $S_2=\{(1,0), (0,0), (0,1), (0.5, 0.5)\}$, then we have $conv(S_2) = conv(S_1)$.
In fact, consider a set $S_1$, if we consider any point $s \in conv(S_1)$, then we have $conv(S_1) = conv (S_1 \cup s)$.  A convex set can be described by using more than one representation.
You might be interested in the notion of convex basis.

I think you meant, when you wrote "if we consider any point $s \in S_1$", to say "if we consider any point $s \in \operatorname{conv}(S_1)$" instead.

Thanks. you are right. :)

Convex basis is given by the minimal set of extreme points (vertices) that generate the convex hull. Hence, my question seems to be asking about that, rather than the Convex hull; which is given by the smallest convex set that contains all the points in the given set. This defn of convex hull, of a set S, is difficult to gel with the set of 'all' convex combinations of the set S. But, you stated that no conditions need imposed on S, rather than on 'which' convex combinations of S are to be chosen.

@jiten I think you need to learn to admit to yourself that you were just wrong. Your claims of errors in the book were, in fact, not errors, and just your own misunderstandings. I'm not sure, from your comments, whether you've even realised this yet.

Here are two possible definitions for the convex hull of a set $S$, denoted $\operatorname{conv}(S)$:

$\operatorname{conv}(S)$ is the minimal convex set with respect to the partial order "$\subseteq$" that contains $S$. In formulas:
$$
\operatorname{conv}(S) = A = \bigcap_{\substack{C \supseteq S \\ C \text{ convex}}} C
$$

$\operatorname{conv}(S)$ is the set of all convex combinations of elements of $S$. In formulas:
$$
\operatorname{conv}(S) = B = \left\{ \sum_{k = 1}^n a_i x_i \;\middle|\; n \in \mathbb{N}, \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k = 1, \forall k : 0 \leq a_k \leq 1, \forall k : x_k \in S \right\}
$$


Here is an outline of the proof that the two sets are equal:

Show that $B$ is actually convex

Show that if $C$ is a convex set with $C \supseteq S$, then $B \subseteq C$

By (1.), deduce that $B \supseteq A$

By (2.), deduce that $B \subseteq A$

Finally, combine (3.) and (4.) to deduce that $B = A$.


